# How to open new tab from background.js in Chrome Extension (Manifest v3)?

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am stuck with creating new tabs in background.js.

`chrome.tabs.create({url: 'https://google.com'})` - doesn’t work, because background.js - is service worker in chrome extensions with (Manifest v3).

Comment: This code works in a service worker so the problem is something else.

Comment: @wOxxOm This code doesn’t open new tab until user open debug page for background service worker

Comment: It means a bug in Chrome or you're not using the service worker correctly: this code should be inside some listener for a `chrome` API event. Add [MCVE](/help/mcve) to the question if further assistance is required.

Answer (score 1):

It happened because I use setTimeut() for executing new tab after some time.

```js
const installationTme = new Date().getTime();
const _timestamp = 10*1000;
function ShowNewPage(){
  if (new Date().getTime() >= installationTme + _timestamp){
     chrome.tabs.create({'url': `https://google.com`}, function(tab) {});
  } else {
     return setTimeout(() => showFeedbackPage(), 2*1000); 
  }
}
```